# non archimedean completion of number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/P(x)$ be a number field, and let $v$ be one of its non-archimedean valuations, corresponding to a prime lying over $p$. What can we say about $K_v$? Can we say $K_v\equiv \mathbb{Q}_p[x]/P(X)$? Is this procedure, gives all of the finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: The valuation corresponds to some prime ideal which divides some rational prime, so yes $K_v$ is an extension of $\Bbb Q_p$. It is true all finite extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$ are completions of number fields.

Comment: @runway44 Thanks. Do we have necessarily this isomorphism $K_v\equiv \mathbb{Q}_p[x]/P(X)$? Probably the answer is No. Since $K_v$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, there should be a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $K_v\equiv \mathbb{Q}_p[x]/Q(X)$. What is the relation between $Q(x)$ and $P(x)$?

Comment: I think the answer is yes, though my memory of p-adic stuff is faded.

Comment: In general, $\mathbb Q_p[x]/P(x) \cong K\otimes_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb Q_p \cong \prod_{v\mid p} K_v$